# React Hooks update a state element when an update of a specific props element occurs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-hooks

Normally not using hooks I used componentWillReceiveProps, but using hooks I can't use them.

How can I update an element of the state when a prop is updated, without going into infinite cycles.

I was trying something like this but I'm going on in endless cycles.

I need to update the datatable when it changes state, or the page etc, then update only specific item if it changes state and is different from the original that was passed.

I thought about doing this, but I don't really like it as a solution.

```
    if(datatable !== state.datatable)
    setState({ ...state, datatable });
```

Can you give me some advice?

```
function Datatable({ header, datatable = [], page = 1, perPage = 5, style }) {
    const [state, setState] = useState({
        datatable,
        page: page - 1,
        perPage,
        numberOfPages: Math.ceil(datatable.length / perPage),
    });

useEffect(() => {
        setState({ ...state, datatable });
 });
 ....
}
```

Comment: `useEffect` accepts a second argument: https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html#tip-optimizing-performance-by-skipping-effects

Answer (score 1):

You need to pass `datatable` as dependency to `useEffect` hook,

```
useEffect(() => {
        setState({ ...state, datatable });
},[datatable]);
```

Now your hook will execute when `datatable` changes only.

Comment: Thank you I had tried, but it didn't work, is there a way to do if a props parameter is updated to update only that without touching the others? Or the only way is to declare so many useEffects, how many props could they change?

Answer (score 1):

It's a bad pattern to put the prop value in a state. In this way, you have two sources of truth for `datatable` value. Additionally, your component will re-render by changing props itself and you don't need to put it in the state.

The following code will do what you want:

```
function Datatable({ header, datatable = [], page = 1, perPage = 5, style }) {
    const [state, setState] = useState({
        page: page - 1,
        perPage,
        numberOfPages: Math.ceil(datatable.length / perPage),
    });
 ....
}
```

Comment: So how would you do? Can you give me an example? You can as truth values use only those of the state, I don't use those of the props, I only use the props to assign the values to the elements of the state

Comment: I update my answer and I hope it solves your problem.